# Network Graph and US Map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, social-networking

I created a network graph from data on flows between US states. For each vertex, I have the lat/long of the state.

I am hoping to recreate a network kind of graph that shows the edges, except that I set the location of each vertex to be their geographic position and have a state boundary map in the background.

I am using to igraph to create my network.  There have been some cool mapping examples in ggplot2, so I am wondering if that is an option.  I believe I have seen similar options using Pajek, but I am hoping to stay within R.

[maps in ggplot2](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/choropleth-challenge-result.html)

Any ideas/insight would be appreciated.

- Brock

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have multiple packages dealing with maps. The most easy is `maps`, which gives you the states map. You can plot the vertices over using the coordinates.

```
map("state")
points(longitute,latitude)
```

These plots can be manipulated and added to using the base tools, keeping in mind the x axis is the longitude and the y axis is the latitude. edges can be plotted using the `segments()` function.

In ggplot2 just use the `map_data()` function, which gives you the shape-data of the map, and the `geom_polygon()` to add it to the graph in whatever form you want. Again, you can add the vertices and edges using the coordinates with the appropriate ggplot2 function `geom_point()` and `geom_segment()`. The code you link at shows you how, or otherwise look at [this](https://gist.github.com/raw/233134/e21097aeb07874a626175410f5a9b3465c62ce59/points.r) for an example.

Next to that, you can take a look at the packages `maptools`, which offers more functionality and, `mapproj`, which allows for different projections of the same map. You can use these packages as well to calculate geographical distances in a coordinate system.

`mapdata` contains more databases, and covers basically the whole world. You can work with coordinates pretty nicely.